# Can Control-M execute a http service endpoint to GET job status?

Tags: web-services, scheduler, job-scheduling, control-m

I am very new to control-m and wanted to ask if control-m supports this scenario:

1. We have a http webservice that runs a log running job e.g.

> `http://myserver/runjob?jobname=A`

This will then start job A on the server and returns a job id back.  I return job id so i can get status of the job from the server when ever i want to.  The job has many statuses e.g. Waiting, In progress, error

1. I want the control-m job status to be updated as soon as the job on the server updates.  For that, I have created a webservice url:

> `http://localhost/getjobsatus?jobid=1`

This url request will get the job status of the job id 1

Can control-m poll a web service url for a job status and can I call a web service to run a job and get its id back?

Apologies for asking this basic level question.  Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: did you solve this using the API call ? On the control-M side, how did you solve it ? I have to monitor some long running API's using control-m

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the Control-M community :-)

You can implement 2 Control-M WebServices jobs (available with BPI – Business Process Integration Suite), one to submit your job and get its ID, and one to track its status.

Alternatively you can implement this in 1 Control-M OS type job using the ctmsubmit command inside a script…

Feel free to join our [Control-M online community](http://communities.bmc.com/community/bmcdn/enterprise_scheduling_workload_automation)

Comment: Could you please explain how to configure webservices jobs?